# Issue toggle on/off with infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

today i saw an answer about toggle on/off in the same button, and i decided to try to use.

What i want is to click in the marker and than a infowindow appear in my map, but it doesn't work.

JSFiddle [simple marker with infowindow](http://jsfiddle.net/hc2azxtr/4/)

JSFiddle [toogle on/off but no infowindow](http://jsfiddle.net/592wts4p/)

When i try to join(toogle with infowindow) like this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(buttonCarrosUI, 'click', function() {
  if(marker && marker.setMap){
      if (marker.getMap() != null)
          marker.setMap(null);
     else marker.setMap(map_canvas);
  }else{
      var myLatLng;
      var title = marker.title;
      $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
          myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);
      });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: title,
      });
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              map: map_canvas,  
              icon: image,
              title: title
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map_canvas,marker);
          });
   }
});
```

I Got this issue

> TypeError: marker is undefined
>
> var title = marker.title;

I'll be very gratefull if someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: Where is the code that generates that error?

Comment: The error is when i try to join both codes, like in the gray part

Comment: Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/uew71c8v/

Comment: That has a different error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: Firebug tells me that marker is not defined lol

Comment: I'm not using firebug, am using Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the marker outside of the $.each. Unless you want more than one infowindow open at a time, it is better to make a global infowindow and reuse it.  Also, you are overwriting the "marker" variable inside the $.each.  Note that this wont work for more than one marker.  You need to keep references to the markers in an array if you have more than one (the original example from which this code came toggled a single polyline).   The code below works for me:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(buttonCarrosUI, 'click', function () {
    var data = JSON;
    var myLatLng;
    if (marker && marker.setMap) {
        if (marker.getMap() != null) marker.setMap(null);
        else marker.setMap(map_canvas);
    } else {
        $.each(data.markers, function (i, markerInfo) {
            myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(markerInfo.latitude, markerInfo.longitude);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map_canvas,
                title: markerInfo.title
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent(marker.getTitle());
                infowindow.open(map_canvas, marker);
            });
        });

    }
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/592wts4p/2/)

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip!! But let me do another question, what i need to do to keep the reference if i want to show more than one infowindow at the same time?

Comment: If you want to show and toggle more than one marker at a time, you need to keep references to them in an array.  If you want to have more than one infowindow open at a time, you need to create one for each marker.  For more than that, try to do it, if you run into trouble ask another question.